# Актив меню при скроллинге по стр

Tags: javascript, html, css

как сделать что бы когда я скроллил на секцию #about к нему прибавлялся класс актив ?

Comment: можно реализовать с помощью pageYOffset

Answer (score 2):

Можно определись с помощью этой функции, а дальше уже навесить

```
function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    const elemTop = rect.top;
    const elemBottom = rect.bottom;
    const isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
    return isVisible;
}
```